# WMIC Java command not working after exe installation

Tags: java, wmic

A very simple code running in the debugging mode perfectly but not working after installation of exe, giving no response/result in return. even no errors to trace.

After building a .exe and installing on my PC its happening, very strange. 
tried process builder but the same thing, anyway to check/trace it. maybe paths ?

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic diskdrive get signature");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
  b.append(line);
}
```

Please note: CMD /c before commands also return an empty response in actual env.

Comment: [When Runtime.exec() won't](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) old _JavaWorld_ article by Michael Daconta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An internal windows command with arguments, like **"wmic diskdrive ..."** 
can be executed easily by ***wrapping it up inside a cmd window.***

**Here is the working code snippet for running the wmic command encapsulated in a cmd window:**

import java.io.*;

public class Wmic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

try {

    // Initialize a process object to run 
    // wmic command and its parameters
    // inside a cmd window

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec("cmd /c C:\\Windows\\System32\\wbem\\WMIC.exe diskdrive get signature");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        b.append(line);
    }

} catch (Exception ex) {
    b.append(ex.toString());
}

System.out.println("Output: \n" + b.toString());
}
```

}

**Output:**

```
>javac Wmic.java

>java Wmic
Output:
Signature
```

**More information:**

https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i already tried to add cmd /c but its same response, after jar deployment. both way only working in debug env or in junit.

Comment: please note, i tried working other way around but its only working in debug mode, not after jar deployment.

Comment: Can you try giving the full path of wmic.exe in the command?  I.E., .exec("cmd /c C:\\Windows\\System32\\wbem\\WMIC.exe diskdrive get signature")?

Comment: Specifying the full path to wmic.exe command had worked. I just verified it on my computer and updated the answer with working code.

Comment: According to Microsoft documentation for [Win32_DiskDrive class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-diskdrive?redirectedfrom=MSDN), _signature_ is a [uint32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint32?view=netcore-3.1), i.e. a number. I don't see a number in the command output that you are getting. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The `ProcessBuilder` constructor takes a list of strings. When using `ProcessBuilder` to run a command, I separate all the words in the command into separate strings.

I read the output of the process in a separate thread. And I always wait for the command, that I launched via `ProcessBuilder`, to terminate.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class PrcBldTs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("wmic","diskdrive","get","signature");
        try {
            Process proc = pb.start();
            StreamGobbler error = new StreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream());
            StreamGobbler output = new StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream());
            Thread stdout = new Thread(output);
            Thread stderr = new Thread(error);
            stdout.start();
            stderr.start();
            int result = proc.waitFor();
            stdout.join();
            stderr.join();
            System.out.println("Exit status = " + result);
            if (result != 0) {
                System.out.println(error.getContents());
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(output.getContents());
            }
        }
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class StreamGobbler implements Runnable {
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private StringWriter sw;

    public StreamGobbler(InputStream is) {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        sw = new StringWriter();
    }

    public String getContents() {
        return sw.toString();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                sw.append(line);
                sw.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            throw new RuntimeException(xIo);
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above code gave me the following output.

```
Exit status = 0
Signature   

1145609371
```